# Is there a reason that we have to use homogeneous coordinates in rasterization?

Tags: opengl, rasterization

Looking at the pipeline of games, I am confused about the necessity of homogeneous coordinates.

For gameplay logic, a 4x3 matrix is enough to handle translation, rotation, and scale. I can't think of anything to require a 4th dimension unless we are making a game of theme about universe, blackhole, time, light speed.

For clipping space, homogeneous clip space just does these things to clip out unwanted parts;
\begin{cases}
      \text{w>0}\\
      \text{|x|<|w|}\\
      \text{|y|<|w|}\\
      \text{|z|<|w|}\\
    \end{cases}
However the `w` is the `-z` value before the final perspective projection. Without a 4th dimension, I can also clip in this way, and map z to the new z value in z-buffer as is.
\begin{cases}
      \text{z<0}\\
      \text{|x|<|z|}\\
      \text{|y|<|z|}\\
      \text{far<z<near}\\
    \end{cases}
The perspective devide can also be done by dividing z, so the point on your screen space is
\$(-x/z, -y/z, z)\$

Someone says we can tell if a vector is a direction or a point by using `w==0` or `w==1`. But when we write shader or game logic, we probably know what is passed to our code and can just call the corresponding transform function.

-----updates on 2024.1.25-----

I got one point wrong. In my model, \$(x, y, z)\$ in camera space is mapped to \$(-x/z, -y/z, z)\$ in screen space. This will make depth interpolation not correct. The correct version is \$(-x/z, -y/z, -1/z)\$. First we do the clipping in the camera space, just clip out anything that's behind the near space, like \$z<0.1\$, and then transform into screen space and render.

Comment: What if you want an orthographic projection? You want a depth buffer, so Z must hold meaningful value, but if you force the division by Z, you get perspective and not orthographic.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat maybe use an if-else statement to decide if divide by z? Or make orthographic as a state of gpu?

Comment: I also believe you need to allow an arbitrary factor to multiply Z by before doing the perspective division, to allow arbitrary FoV angles. (Or customizable range of Z for clipping and depth buffer, which is effectively the same thing.)

Comment: Whether there's value in allowing X and Y to influence the W (aka using a 4x4 matrix) I don't know.

Comment: Well, to apply arbitrary fov, I can insert a scale transform using a 3x3 matrix. At clipping step, z is simply compared with near and far. For the common 4x4 approach, in the final camera space, x and y will not affect the transformed w value.

Comment: What I'm saying is, how are you going to switch between those two frustums, for example: https://i.imgur.com/fDLl3FQ.png You can't scale Z, because that would also move near and far planes, and let's assume we don't want that. Can't scale XY, because that wouldn't give you the resired result (that would preserve the ratio between nead and far plane width, which isn't what we want). The only option is to adjust the Z->W factor.

Comment: I see the problem. In many CAD software, if I click "orthographic", it will show me a smoothly animated transformation between perspective and orthographic. This animation can only be handled perfectly using homogeneous coordinates. Let's say t=0 means standard perspective, and t=1 means standard orthographic. As t goes up, the homogeneous-coordinated camera can stay at its position, while my camera needs to move itself back, push the far and near plane away, and turn down the fov. When it comes to the end of the animation, like t=0.99, my camera will be quite far away.

Comment: At this point, float32 precision is not able to handle it and some artifacts will come out. And finally t=1, the orthographic state of the GPU is set and the artifacts go away.